# Salesforce - Unable to create/update fields: IsVisibleInCsp

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities, salesforce-lightning

I was able to create and publish knowledge article via salesforce API.
After published, the default channel is set to **Internal App**

My problem is 
I am trying to set or add new channel **Customer** via api using this field **IsVisibleInCsp** = true so that the customer is able to view the published article. but it throws and error

> [      {
>         "message":"Unable to create/update fields: IsVisibleInCsp. Please 
>      check the security settings of this field and verify that it is
>   read/write for your profile or permission set.",
>         "errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE",
>         "fields":[
>            "IsVisibleInCsp"
>         ]    } ]

This is my current script

```
JSON_OBJECT=$(jq -n "{\"Summary\" : \"$ARTICLE_SUMMARY\",\"title\" : \"$ARTICLE_TITLE\",\"IsVisibleInCsp\" : \"true\",\"UrlName\" : \"$ARTICLE_URL_NAME\",ArticleBody__c:\"$result\"}")
#echo $JSON_OBJECT
json=`curl -s -X POST $INSTANCE_URL/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Knowledge__kav/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$ACCESS_TOKEN -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$JSON_OBJECT"`
```

please help me.

thank you!

Comment: I think nothing to do with JS,  All the fields are not writable form API So check it out admin side and object side. For more https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008qFMIAY

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Will do a check on this. I'll update you